# Make dropdowns show up one at a time

Tags: jquery, dropdown

I'm trying to make my dropdowns show up one at a time but they are showing up all at once.

Any suggestions?

```
$(".setbutton").on("click", function(){
    $("#sub-nav-set").toggle();
});
$(".searchbutton").on("click", function(){
    $("#sub-nav-search").toggle();
});
$(".viewbutton").on("click", function(){
    $("#sub-nav-view").toggle();
});
$(".newbutton").on("click", function(){
    $("#sub-nav-new").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Can you please show the relevant HTML?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please provide an HTML output, so that it will be more easier for us to read. You can check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's actually just a refactoring exercise, so HTML output isn't needed. All of the elements will toggle open if clicked and remain open, I just need to figure out how to use jQuery to close all the open elements should a different item be selected.